# How calculate information gain of a word given a set of text?

Tags: python, machine-learning

Given a database containing phrases

Example:

1. check work slow
2. work wallpapers
3. work needed reply notification working groups

I need to calculate the information gain for each distinct word.

1. IG('work')
2. IG('check')
3. ....

I studied the concepts of entropy and information gain but I'm not sure how to apply it in phrases.
I saw this link: https://mariuszprzydatek.com/2014/10/31/measuring-entropy-data-disorder-and-information-gain/
But in my case I have no phrase categories.
I need to know which words has greatest infogain given only the phrases.

Comment: This is more appropriate for CrossValidated, I think, rather than StackOverflow.

Comment: You first need to set a value to each sentence before you can figure out how much each word can give you. And you would need more that three sentences. That is much too small of a training set

Comment: Thank you. My set has 30000 phrases, this is a simple example to explain better. How do you define a value for each sentence? Manually?

Comment: well you would usually find the info gain of a feature of set of data. I'm assuming you are using the words as features for your sentences. to find the info gain of a feature (or in your case, a word) you need the total value for the set of data. you could define the value of the sentence as a binary i.e. "do this" or "don't do this" it might mean a level of how much do do something i.e. on a scale from 1 to 10. it depends on what the sentences mean

Comment: Thanks Buzz. Best

Answer (score 0):

Search for the term **tf-idf**.
Read this Question, your term **set of text** == **document**.

[interpreting-the-sum-of-tf-idf-scores-of-words-across-documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269313/interpreting-the-sum-of-tf-idf-scores-of-words-across-documents/42369493#42369493)