# Keyword based summarization

Tags: python, nltk, summarization

I am wondering if there are some automatic summarization algorithms who handle extraction based on a custom dictionary. I’ve been using textrank based algorithms for a while now, but I want to have an impact on the ranking of phrases that the algorithm calculates.

**Example**

> "Thomas A. Anderson is a man living two lives. By day he is an average
>   computer programmer and by night a hacker known as Neo. Neo has always
>   questioned his reality, but the truth is far beyond his imagination.
>   Neo finds himself targeted by the police when he is contacted by
>   Morpheus, a legendary computer hacker branded a terrorist by the
>   government. Morpheus awakens Neo to the real world, a ravaged
>   wasteland where most of humanity have been captured by a race of
>   machines that live off of the humans' body heat and electrochemical
>   energy and who imprison their minds within an artificial reality known
>   as the Matrix. As a rebel against the machines, Neo must return to the
>   Matrix. He must confront the agents: super-powerful computer programs
>   devoted to snuffing out Neo and the entire human rebellion."

My custom dictionary would look like something like this:

```
super-powerful: [important]
Thomas A. Anderson: [important]
```

My summary should contain the following sentences, even if their ranking is lower than some other sentences in the paragraph:

> 1. "Thomas A. Anderson is a man living two lives"
> 2. "He must confront the agents: super-powerful computer programs devoted to snuffing out Neo and the entire human rebellion."

I've tried to reach this by adding extra tags to my POS-tagged sentences, it looks like this:

```
[[('Thomas A. Anderson', 'Thomas A. Anderson', ['important']), ('is', 'is', ['VBZ']), ('a', 'a', ['DT']), ('man', 'man', ['NN']), ('living', 'living', ['VBG']), ('two', 'two', ['CD']), ('lives', 'lives', ['NNS'])]]

[[('He', 'He', ['PRP']), ('must', 'must', ['MD']), ('confront', 'confront', ['VB']), ('the', 'the', ['DT']), ('agents', 'agents', ['NNS']), (':', ':', [':']), ('super-powerful', 'super-powerful', ['important', 'JJ']), ('computer', 'computer', ['NN']), ('programs', 'programs', ['NNS']), ('devoted', 'devoted', ['VBD']), ('to', 'to', ['TO']), ('snuffing', 'snuffing', ['VBG']), ('out', 'out', ['RP']), ('Neo', 'Neo', ['NNP']), ('and', 'and', ['CC']), ('the', 'the', ['DT']), ('entire', 'entire', ['JJ']), ('human', 'human', ['JJ']), ('rebellion', 'rebellion', ['NN']), ('.', '.', ['.'])]]
```

But I don't really know how I can tell the textrank algorithm to give priority at sentences with those tags. I've used Python with nltk and yaml to reach this output

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Read this SO Q&A, maybe you can use ths: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269313/interpreting-the-sum-of-tf-idf-scores-of-words-across-documents

Comment: What TextRank algorithm do you use? is it publicly available?