# Gensim find topics in sentences

Tags: python, gensim

I have trained an LDA algorithm on a corpus , and what I'd like to do is getting for each sentence the topic on which it corresponds, in order, to make a comparison between what the algorithm finds and the labels I have.

I have tried with the code below, but the results are quite bad I find a great deal of topic 17 (maybe 25% of the volume, it should be closer to 5%)

Thanks for your help

```
# text lemmatized: list of string lemmatized
dico = Dictionary(texts_lemmatized)
corpus_lda = [dico.doc2bow(text) for text in texts_lemmatized]

lda_ = LdaModel(corpus_lda, num_topics=18)

df_ = pd.DataFrame([])
data = []

# theme_commentaire = label of the string
for i in range(0, len(theme_commentaire)):
     # lda_.get_document_topics() gives the distribution of all topic for a specific sentence
     algo = max(lda_.get_document_topics(corpus_lda[i]))[0]
     human = theme_commentaire[i]
     data.append([str(algo), human])

cols = ['algo', 'human']
df_ = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
df_.head()
```

Comment: Read this relevant SO Question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42269313/7414759

Comment: it's not really relevant my problem is about LDA not TfIDF. I've found my problem though, It's the max() function, it operates on the key value of my list of tuple [(num_topics, probability)] so basically I'll get 17 most of the time because it's the biggest key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved in comments:

> I've found my problem though,  It's the max() function, it operates on the key value of my list of tuple 
>   [(num_topics, probability)] so basically I'll get 17 most of the time because it's the biggest key. – glouis