# How to apply TFIDF to find important words in csv file using pycharm

Tags: python, csv, nltk, tf-idf

I have a file that includes some data,

An example of the data I have

```
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  SOC Code  |              Title              |  Occupational Category  |
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 11-1011.03 | Chief Sustainability Officers   | New & Emerging          |
| 11-1021.00 | General and Operations Managers | Enhanced Skills         |
+------------+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I need to find the most frequent words in the file 
Any ideas on how can this be applied? pieces of codes would be appreciated as an example

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Check out the wikipedia entry on TF-IDF and you'll see that it is not meaningful if you have a single document -- you need a collection of many documents, and TF-IDF chooses among them. You probably need a different metric, and you definitely need a better problem statement. Note that on this site, _you_ give us pieces of code and we help you improve it.

Comment: Read this relevant Q: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42269313/7414759

Comment: This has nothing to do with PyCharm. It's just an editor. You can write a Python program to operate on CSV files in any number of editors.

Answer (score 0):

You could count the words using the NLTK `FreqDist` method and return the most frequent ones.